# String to XNamespace Implicit Conversion inside a BizTalk Orchestration

Tags: c#-4.0, linq-to-xml, biztalk, biztalk-2010

I am a bit confused by what I see and hence headed over to SO.

I am developing a BizTalk (2010) Orchestration and I am wanting to parse an incoming XML message. I just need to retrieve then number of times a particular node is repeating. I could have used XPath. But, I chose to use LinqToXml.

I have created a variable of type `System.Xml.Linq.XNamespace` and inside an expression shape, I am assignning it a string value.. say `http://mycompany/v1.0`. This is a perfectly valid C# statment, as there is an implicit conversion from String to XNamespace ([MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xnamespace.op_implicit.aspx)).

But the Orchestration will not compile at all. I get this error `cannot implicitly convert type System.String to System.Xml.Linq.XNamespace`.

And if I dont use the XNamespace variable and directly run LinqToXml on the incoming message like this

```
MessageCount = MyXElement.Elements("{http://mycompany/v1.0}ListOfNotifications").Elements("{http://mycompany/v1.0}Notification").Count();
```

I get a `cannot convert from String to XName` error. Even this is confusing.

I am using BizTalk 2010 and C# 4.0. Can someone explain if I am missing something? I have tried all these code snippets using LinqPad and I get the expected response. So, there are no typos or missing references.

Comment: Are there more than one instance of **ListOfNotifications**?

Comment: @user1826905: Nope. There is just one

Comment: Not in your XML, in your schema. How is that element defined? Is it unbounded?

Comment: @user1826905: Yes. It is unbounded

Comment: Then you need to select the first one not just the node i.e. index 1 of **ListOfNotifications**.

Comment: @user1826905: Sorry. That did not work either. Thanks for the suggestion. I have decided to use the `XPath` option.

Answer (score 0):

I opted to use the `XPath` option to retrieve the values that I needed, instead of using LinqToXml. The code that I ended up writing looks like below:

```
xpath(myOrchVariable, "string(/*[local-name()='InputRootNode' and namespace-uri()='http://my/name/space'])")
```